# Select row with conditions column value

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A         B    C
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  120
1  2002-01-13  15:30:00  110
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  130
3  2002-01-13  16:30:00  140
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  180
5  2002-01-14  15:30:00  165
6  2002-01-14  16:00:00  150
7  2002-01-14  16:30:00  170
```

I want to select one row per each *A group*, with next conditions:

- Select the *"minimum C column value + 10"*.
- If it doesn´t exist *"minimum C column value + 10"*, take the next *C column value*.

Output should be:

```
            A         B    C
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  120
5  2002-01-14  15:30:00  165
```

Comment: Eliminate all the values that are lower than minimum + 10 and then perform a groupby and get the min?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Anton vBR commented, first remove rows by condition per groups and then get rows by minimal `C` by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and select by `loc`:

```
df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: x >= x.min() + 10)]
#filtering with  transform `min` only
#df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('min') + 10 <= df['C']]
print (df)
            A         B    C
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  120
2  2002-01-13  16:00:00  130
3  2002-01-13  16:30:00  140
4  2002-01-14  15:00:00  180
5  2002-01-14  15:30:00  165
7  2002-01-14  16:30:00  170

df = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['C'].idxmin()]
```

What is same as:

```
idx=df.sort_values(['A','C']).groupby('A')['C'].apply(lambda x: (x >= x.min() + 10).idxmax())
df = df.loc[idx]
```

Alternative solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['A','C'])
df = df[df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda x: x >= x.min() + 10)].drop_duplicates(['A'])
```

---

```
print (df)
            A         B    C
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  120
5  2002-01-14  15:30:00  165
```

Comment: Not me, I have no reason

Answer (score 1):

This is one vectorised solution. Sometimes a helper column is more efficient than an in-line `lambda`-based solution.

```
df['Floor'] = df['C'] - (df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('min') + 10)

res = df.loc[df[df['Floor'] >= 0].groupby('A')['Floor'].idxmin()]
```

Result:

```
            A         B    C  Floor
0  2002-01-13  15:00:00  120      0
5  2002-01-14  15:30:00  165      5
```